# A button that spawns a hidden template doesn't function on Acrobat Reader using iPad

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat, reader, pdf-reader

within Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, I inserted a buttons that spawns hidden templates (basically duplicated pages) via Javascript. This function works within any desktop application, however, as soon as I try to use it for the iPad/Android Tablet, the button is recognized but it is not functioning. Why does the transition to mobile devices disable the functionality of the button that creates the pages when the button is clicked? This PDF that I am editing will be used on iPads and needs to spawn these duplicated pages with similar form fields.

Following Javascript I'm using.

```
var f = this.getField("c1");
if(f.isBoxChecked(0)){
this.getTemplate("2").spawn();
   }
else {
     this.deletePages(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat Reader for iPad is too dumb. You may look for a better PDFviewer for iPad, although I am not sure whether the leader of the pack, PDFExpert by Readdle supports Templates.

You may have to deal with a server-based solution.

Comment: PDFExpert also doesn't support this function please any other suggestion